# require packages of other modules

Tags: node.js

Im writing some code in Node.js,  using this library, https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2, this  depends of other library https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql  and one more time node-mysql depends of  other https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all

On my app i want to use, the last module , node-require-all, outside of all of the libraries.

I know i can write the next code:

```
var reqall  = require("orm/node_modules/mysql/node_modules/require-all");
```

But im not sure if this is good.

should I add, the library in my project instead off this with?

npm install require-all?.

and later:

```
var reqall = require("require-all");
```

or is good use the first way?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to directly add `require-all` to your dependencies in `package.json`.

In this case, [according to node-mysql package.json](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/package.json), the require-all version will be 0.0.3.  However, [the latest version of require-all](https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all/blob/master/package.json) is 0.0.8, so if you want to use the latest version you have to specify it

Comment: Ok!,  you have a reason, about the versions :) , this means every time i want to use a library is already loaded into other library is better installing  on my app with npm?

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez its always better to add your direct dependencies to package.json

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the require-all package versions are the same between the project and the other included packages, npm will not download it a second time.